# What physically happens inside a wire when voltage is increased but current is constant?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm studying electromagnetism and I'm trying to understand voltage, power etc.

I have two cellphone chargers, on the back of each they list their output.
One has 2.0A and 5.0V, the other has 2.0A and 5.3V.

The cables of the chargers are identical.

So both cables presumably pass 2.0A through them while charging.
The first cable passes P=UI = 10W through it while charging, while the other passes P=UI = 10.6W.

So one cable passes 0.6 Watts more power through it with the same amperage as the other cable.

Since more energy is being passed through one cable, I wonder what is actually **physically** different inside the cables while charging? (e.g electron speed, field strength)

Comment: It is *not* true that the 1st charger passes 2.0A at 5V and the 2nd charger passes 2.0A at 5.3V for the *same* load. All that means is that the *maximum* current is 2.0A for either charger. For the same load R the currents are 5.0/R and 5.3/R, respectively. If R=5$\Omega$ then one will charge at 1A and the other at 1.06A. If you draw more than 2.0A the indicated limit then depending on its construction the charger may melt, explode or just shut down....

Comment: @hyportnex Ah yes, the loads are different (different cell phones), forgot to say that

Answer (score 1):

> So one cable passes 0.6 Watts more power through it with the same amperage as the other cable.

A cable generally contains multiple wires. In this case the important ones are a positively charged "power" wire and a "ground" or "return" wire. Power doesn't pass through the individual wires. Power is actually transferred by the electric fields between the wires in the cable.

> Since more energy is being passed through one cable, I wonder what is actually physically different inside the cables while charging?

Inside the wires of the cable, nothing is different. The electric field between the positive wire and the negative wire of the cable is higher when there's a larger potential difference between them.